# HDMI to TV keeps dimming in and out?

Tags: hdmi

I connected my Asus ZenBook running Ubuntu 13 to my TV (Panasonic) via HDMI. My main problem is that when I'm watching a movie the screen keeps dimming in and out. It doesn't dim all the way out, just becomes darker for a few seconds and then gradually brightens back to normal, then after a few minutes dims again and so on.

Tried using different video players like VLC, Dragon, and the built in video player, but to no avail. And have not been able to find any useful threads on the subject. Please help.. my girlfriend might leave me or decline to come over if we have to keep watching movies only on the laptop.

I'll be happy to post any additional info needed to solve this.

Comment: are you sure this isn't your TV doing the dimming? Some TVs have an auto brightness setting which will adjust the brightness of the screen depending on the colours currently displayed on the screen (ie: will get dimmer when the screen has more white on it and lighter when the screen has more dark on it)

Comment: yeah it was the tv in end. in this specific model there are viewing modes. "Normal" does a weird auto dimming thing whereas "True Cinema" works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many modern TVs with LED dim the backlight. The most bright point oft the picture (50% of the color range for example) will be 100% brightness of the pixel, and the backlight dims to 50%.
This is called dynamic contrast.

Comment: that wasn't exactly the case with my tv but it was a different setting as in my comment above. the important bottom line is there isn't a problem with ubuntu and hdmi.

Comment: I am sure it's like I explained, it will dim for dark scenes which is really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an temp solution that works...

The dimming mechanism scans the outer edges of the screen - if you bring up a Google [white] screen and then place your movie/game screen inside it leaving about 0.5 inch" around the outside it won't dim...